Pandas load json from file and save to excel - ValueError
I'm running a simple python test to read json and output to excel.
I'm get the following error:
"ValueError("All arrays must be of the same length")"
JSON file example (test data)
{
    "content": [
        {
            "id": "test_id",
            "url": "http://www.google.com/",
            "path1": "dir1/dir1_subdir_1/hello.txt",
            "path2": "external://hello.txt",
            "revision": "613592",
            "ChangedDate": "2024-01-01T17:00:00+00:00",
            "ChangedRevision": "12345",
            "tags": [],
            "Revision": {
                "id": "2468",
                "revision": "987654",
                "revisionSource": "google",
                "url": "http://www.google.com"
            }
        }
    ],
    "requestId": "12345",
    "errors": [],
    "warnings": [],
    "information": [],
    "isValid": true
}

I don't need the last 5 lines in the output file
Python code
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json("simple.json",).to_excel("json_output.xlsx", index=False)




Assuming you only need content from the json file, you can first use json.load and then use it to create dataframe:
import pandas as pd
import json

with open('simple.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data['content'])
# output to excel
df.to_excel("json_output.xlsx", index=False)


Thank you.  That worked.  One follow-up.  I'm a newbie manipulating json.  How do i separate out 'Revision' items into separate columns?  Right now the entire section is in a single column

Instead of df = pd.DataFrame(data['content']), you can use df = pd.json_normalize(data['content']), it should expand to separate columns. json_normalize normalizes semi-structured JSON data into a flat table. See more https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html

Excellent.  Thank you for help!

Glad it worked. Happy Coding! Please consider marking this as solution.
